# Vuforia builds fail on iOS 17

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Every time I build from Unity 2022.3.15.f1 a simple Vuforia test project for iOS 17 Xcode 15.1 gives me the error below. For some reason, the Unity build is putting the required frameworks in the wrong place and I am trying to figure out how to point to their location.

> Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/15175FA5-6EE1-4AD2-8618-1B0CF1A76AE1/Vuforia-01.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (137):  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/15175FA5-6EE1-4AD2-8618-1B0CF1A76AE1/Vuforia-01.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine
>   Referenced from:  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/15175FA5-6EE1-4AD2-8618-1B0CF1A76AE1/Vuforia-01.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
>   Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/15175FA5-6EE1-4AD2-8618-1B0CF1A76AE1/Vuforia-01.app/Frameworks/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/15175FA5-6EE1-4AD2-8618-1B0CF1A76AE1/Vuforia-01.app/Frameworks/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/15175FA5-6EE1-4AD2-8618-1B0CF1A76AE1/Vuforia-01.app/Frameworks/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine' (no such file)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the 'General' settings in Xcode scroll down to 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content' and click the plus button and then browse to the frameworks folder. In my case there are two folders that are red. 'com.ptc.vuforia.engine' and 'com.unity.ads'. Drill down into these folders and add all the frameworks to the project.  This process is unintuitive. I don't remember having to go through this when I used older versions of Vuforia and Unity.

Comment: Does this happen when compiling the Vuforia Core Samples? https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-core-samples-99026

Comment: Yes. Code samples or creating the scene from scratch. Same every time.

Comment: Unity released a patch 2022.3.16f1 which might fix your issue. Please try to upgrade.

Comment: emay you are correct. The patch fixed it. Thanks!